# Loading PEAR dependencies from different locations?

Tags: php, dependencies, pear

I'm trying to load the `Mail` extension on my cloud hosting server, but it's failing as I have dependencies in multiple locations.

`Mail` and `Net` were installed via cPanel, and they were installed in `/home/username/php`.

The [spec](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php) for `Mail` says to `require 'Mail.php'`, which would then load it from the `include_path`. However, the `include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php`. This is where `PEAR.php` is, as well as other stuff I don't know about.

So,

If I use `require '/home/username/php/Mail.php`, Mail's dependencies such as `Net_SMTP` fail to load.

If I change the include path to `/home/username/php`, then `PEAR.php` fails to load.

I'd rather not have to modify the `Mail.php` to manually include it's dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your include path to reference all directories concerned:

```
include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/username/php/'
```